# Hasura adding text[] in table schema

Tags: postgresql, hasura

I am creating table's schema in of **Employee** entity in **Hasura**, and i need to add an attribute called **listOfSpokenLanguages** of type String array, in postgres i can easily do it using text[], but is there a way i can do the same in Hasura.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently do this in Hasura console, you'll have to do it via manual SQL.

However Hasura does support `text[]` type after it is added to the table.

https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/insert.html#insert-an-object-with-an-array-field

Answer (score 0):

On the console, when you add a new column to your table, you can write the type `Text[]` inside the `column_type` field (to force the array)

I uploaded a gif showing how to do this here: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/348#issuecomment-716923033

Ps: as mentioned [here](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/3616#issuecomment-570164399),

> We recommend you to use one to many relationships instead of arrays if that's a right fit for your data.